# Ajax 'POST' value to another page without using hidden field & form

Tags: php, ajax

Is that possible to pass a value without using form & hidden field?
I try the ajax but not working. Below is my code

../order/?step=0 code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    var step0 = [];
    var item = {
        pid: 123,
        qty: 1
    };
    step0.push({0:item});
    data = JSON.stringify(step0);
    $("a.base-product").click(function() {  
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../order/?step=1',
            data: data,
        });
    });
});
</script>

<a class= "base-product" href="../order/?step=1">next</a>
```

After I click the next  link, will need to ask the data from ajax to ../order/?step=1

../order/?step=1:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

But I get Array();

Or is that able to use the $_SESSION?

Comment: Please specify ContentType header as application/json. refer this: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/ajax-with-contenttype-application-json

Comment: @MakAnsari I want to post value from page A to page B, the situation not same as your link.

Comment: When you press 'next' link then you wanted to pass some hidden data from current page to order page. right??

Comment: @MakAnsari nope. My question is pass the value without having form or hidden input when I clicked "next"

Comment: The `?step=1` part is in the link, not part of the POST data. So use `$_GET` to retrieve

Comment: @Michel I want to post the {pid:123, qty:1} from ?step=0 to ?step=1. This data can't not show public.I am not try to get the step number in url param.

Comment: PHP does not populate $_POST, if you send JSON. In that case, you need to read it using this method, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php

Comment: @CBroe thanks. I tried and it only return me string(0) "" or blank or Null, I event use the contentType in ajax. Is this not possible to POST via ajax?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="title">Post title:</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="My excellent blog post">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="content">Post content:</label>
    <textarea id="content" name="content" cols="60" rows="5">
This is the content of my excellent blog post. I hope you enjoy it!
    </textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Update post</button>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="postId" name="postId" value="34657">
</form>
```

Comment: title "post a js value without using hidden field & form to another page"